# Take 0 as NULL when filling NULL values in DolphinDB

Tags: null, dolphindb

Using DolphinDB to fill NULL values, how can I handle 0 in the same way as NULL?

Answer (score 0):

For me I will `replace` 0 to NULL and then do the `nullFill`.